# How to pass parameter in stored procedure for SQL IN and what should be the data type?

Tags: mysql

```
$$DELIMITER
PROCEDURE MYSP(
 IN some_parameter_name datatype(size)
)
BEGIN
  SELECT * FROM X WHERE FIELD IN (some_parameter_name);
END$$
```

This is what i want to execute. What should be the data type of "**some_parameter_name**", I tried with varchar, but it didn't work. & In php end it was like

```
$x = "'1','2','3'";
mysqli_query($con,CALL MYSP($X));
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check ,It should be like :

```
DELIMITER $$
PROCEDURE MYSP(
 IN param varchar(50)
)
BEGIN
  SELECT * FROM X WHERE FIELD IN (param);
END$$
```

Hope this will work.